# Where should i set a Variable if want to access it in my whole React app?

Tags: reactjs

Hi Guys Now i'm working on some modification in a React app and i am just a beginner , i have a Question , now i have a const called Users List it Goes like This :

```
"u_469": {
         "ID": "469",
         "UID": "HEA009",
         "Name": "XXXX XXXX",
         "Position": "QCO",
         "Shift": "A",
         "u_id": "u_469",
         "img": "u_469.png"
      }
   , ...
```

Instead of working like this i made an api where i will retrieve the Users list , but the problem is the old Users List (const) is all Over the Components , The Question is how Or where should i make my axios request so all the Components access the response instead of the const .

```
import axios from "axios";
import {useState , useEffect} from "react";
import {LINK_ROUTES} from './const';

const USERS_LIST = (props) => {
    const [USERs_LIST, setUSERs_LIST] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post(LINK_ROUTES.links.getUsersDropdown).then((response) => {
            setUSERs_LIST(response.data.data);
        })
    },[]);
}
export default  USERS_LIST ;
```

I've tried this and call it in the other Components but it doesn't Work .

Answer (score 2):

You can use **useContext** to share state across all your components.

**First Make this file**

```js
import React from "react";
const DataLayerContext = React.createContext();

const DataLayerProvider = (props) => {
  const [USERs_LIST, setUSERs_LIST] = useState({});
  return (
      <DataLayerContext.Provider value={{
          USERs_LIST, setUSERs_LIST
       }}
       >
      </DataLayerContext.Provider>
      )
  }

export { DataLayerProvider, DataLayerContext }
```

**Then wrap the Data Layer around your app.js as seen below**

```js
import { DataLayerProvider } from "./provider/DataLayer";
export default function App() {
 return (
    <>
      <DataLayerProvider>
        <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="packscreen" headerMode="none"  >
            <Stack.Screen name="packscreen" component={PackScreen}  />
            <Stack.Screen name="namescreen" component={NameScreen}  />
            <Stack.Screen name="cardscreen" component={CardScreen}  />
            <Stack.Screen name="settingscreen" component={SettingScreen}  />
            <Stack.Screen name="subscreen" component={SubScreen}  />
            <Stack.Screen name="termscreen" component={TermsScreen}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="privacyscreen" component={PrivacyScreen}/>
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </DataLayerProvider>
    </>
)
}
```

**Then do something like this in a parent file**

```js
import { DataLayerContext } from "./DataLayer"; 

 const App = (props)=>{ 
    const DATA_LAYER = React.useContext(DataLayerContext)
    const [loading,setLoading] = React.useState(true);

     useEffect(() => {
        axios.post(LINK_ROUTES.links.getUsersDropdown).then((response) => {
            DATA_LAYER.setUSERs_LIST(response.data.data);
             setLoading(false);
        })
       
    },[]);
    
    if (loading){
        // Show loading screen real quickly
        return (
           <View></View>
       )
    }
     
    return (
       <View> 
        
      </View>)
  }
```

**Now you can access this value anywhere in the app by doing this**

```js
   import { DataLayerContext } from "./DataLayer";

   const ScreenA = (props)=>{ 
        const DATA_LAYER = React.useContext(DataLayerContext)
        console.log(DATA_LAYER.USERs_LIST);
   }
```

Comment: Hi Sir , i've tried ur Code it gave this Error :

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setUSERs_LIST')

Comment: you also have to wrap the data layer around all the components of your app look at my new edit